# Allow element's after and before content to override parent overflow restriction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` whose `overflow` property is set to `scroll` in order to see all the contained fields without taking too much of the page's space. Each field has a span (the field's title) and input associated. I offer the possibility to the users to hover on the spans and see some useful information as a tool tip. I use the spans `after` and `before` pseudo-elements on the spans hover in order to add a customized tool tip. However, the tool tips display is restricted by the parent div overflow restriction.

Here is an example of the rendered HTML:

```
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_leftDiv" class="l-custom-left">     
    <div class="personalizedFields">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span title="Champ associé: Prenom" class="tooltip">Prénom</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucPF$ucCustomField36$field36" type="text" id="field36" />

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span title="Champ associé: Nom" class="tooltip">Nom</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucPF$ucCustomField37$field37" type="text" id="field37" />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css of the parent div and spans:

```
.l-custom-left
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50vh;
}

.tooltip:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
}

.tooltip:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

How can I allow my spans after and before content to "override" the div parent overflow restriction?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BishopBarber/n9szycz1/)

Comment: What do you mean by "override"? What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: @Vucko I'd like the before and after content of my spans to overflow, but not my spans, if that makes sense. If you look at my JSFiddle, I'd like the possibility to scroll the fields to persist, but correctly show all the "tooltips". If you hover the first one, per example, you can see it is not shown because of the `overflow-x: hidden;`.

Comment: Well, I get what the problem is but I doubt there is a way to override parents `overflow`. However, I would put the tooltip for the first two elements under the input, and the rest tooltips over the inputs - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/n9szycz1/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want this to work, there are two ways.  The first is to use JavaScript (which I won't go into) to place an element outside the container at the position of the element.  It's an obnoxious fix, and I've had to implement it too many times to count prior to the advent of CSS3.

The second is much more elegant, but does break semantics for HTML.  The reason that your `:before` and `:after` pseudos won't pop out of a scrolling container is that they're treated like children of the `.tooltip` element, and thus part of the document flow for the scrolling container even if they're positioned absolutely.

So how do we handle this?  We cheat, plain and simple.

Add a second element after your `span` like so:

```
<span class="tooltip">Prénom</span>
<span title="Champ associé: Prenom" class="tooltip-hovershim">Prénom</span>
```

We keep the same content so that the element will be the same size.

Then, alter your CSS like this:

```
.tooltip, .tooltip-hovershim
{
    display: inline;
}

.tooltip:hover:after, .tooltip-hovershim:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
}
.tooltip-hovershim { 
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    color: transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover:before, .tooltip-hovershim:hover:before {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Et voila!  Vous avez votre élément flottant.  It's that simple.

## [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n9szycz1/2/)

<sup>Only applied to the first two elements for brevity's sake.</sup>

---

Just for shits and giggles, here's the Javascript variant

## [JSFiddle with the JS variant](http://jsfiddle.net/n9szycz1/3/)

And here's the crucial portion of Javascript:

```
var span_labels = document.querySelectorAll('.personalizedFields td span'),
    label_house = document.createElement('div');

document.body.appendChild(label_house);
label_house.setAttribute('class', 'tooltip-hoverer');

for (var i=0,l=span_labels.length;i<l;i++){
  var curr_label = span_labels[i];
    curr_label.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       label_house.innerHTML = e.target.getAttribute('title');
       var xy = getOffset(e.target);
       label_house.style.top = (xy.top - 26) + 'px';
       label_house.style.left = (xy.left) + 'px';
       label_house.style.display = 'block';
    });
    curr_label.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
       label_house.style.display = 'none'; 
    });
}
                                
function getOffset(el) {
    var elementRectangle = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var _x = elementRectangle.left;
    var _y = elementRectangle.top + el.offsetParent.scrollTop;
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}
```

Comment: Probably need to use JS.  Just so happens I added a JS solution too.

Comment: Part of the problem there is that as soon as you give the container a `relative` position, this solution no longer works.  It's just the realities of document flow.  That's a super helpful solution for when you're just trying to escape an `overflow: hidden`, but forgot the nuances of the `overflow: scroll` and `position: absolute` interaction.

Comment: Thank you, you cleared my mind on a lot of points. I'll go with the JS solution to achieve my needs.

Comment: Last question Josh. How can I find the span (which is inside the scrollable div)'s position relative to window? Or perhaps I don't have the correct logic? In your fiddle, if you scroll down the div, you can see the tool tips positions aren't quite correct, because they are relative to the div. I've tried a lot of things and I feel like I'm looking at things from the wrong angle.

Comment: A new day, a new fresh mind... I found a solution that works no matter how much you scroll inside the div and no matter how much you scroll in the page. [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BishopBarber/n9szycz1/5/). If you want, you can put this in your answer. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks @BishopBarber.  Though I really don't deserve the answer if you answer it yourself. ;)

Comment: I only put the cherry on the cake, whereas you provided me with the cake.

Answer (score 1):

Since what I wanted to do isn't feasible with only CSS, I decided to go with a mix of JavaScript and JQuery, inspired by Josh Burgess's JS solution. So if you were looking for a more JQuery oriented solution, here it is:

```
var tooltip;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.tooltip').on({
        mouseenter: function (e) {
            tooltip = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(tooltip);
            $(tooltip).addClass('tooltip-hoverer');
            $(tooltip).text($(this).attr('data-tooltip'));
            var x = e.clientX - (($(tooltip).outerWidth()) / 2); // "($(tooltip).outerWidth() / 2)" is required to show the tooltip's down arrow next to the mouse's left position
            var y = this.getBoundingClientRect().top + this.offsetParent.scrollTop;
            $(tooltip).css({
                top: y - 32,
                left: x,
                display: 'block'
            });
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            document.body.removeChild(tooltip);
        }
    });                       
});
```

Note that unlike Josh's solution, I don't create all the tool tips at load, but only one each time a span is hovered, then I remove it when the cursor leaves the span.

## [JSFiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/BishopBarber/tjmcp8xs/2/)